# Converting internationally formatted strings to numeric

Tags: r

I have a file with internationally formatted numbers (i.e strings) including units of measurement. In this case the decimal place is indicated by "," and the 1e3 seperator is indicated as "." (i.e. German number formats).

```
a <- c('2.200.222   €',
       '  180.109,3 €')
```

or

```
b <- c('28,42 m²',
       '47,70 m²')
```

I'd like to convert these strings efficiently to `numeric`. I've tried to filter out numbers by codes like

```
require(stringr)
str_extract(a, pattern='[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+')
str_extract(b, pattern='[0-9]+,[0-9]+')
```

however, this does seem to be too prone to errors and I guess there must be a more standardized way. So here's my question: Is there a custom function, package or something else that is capable of such a problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you maybe discuss some of the errors you're seeing?

Comment: actually I'm not sure how to specify the regex. for example, is `'[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+,[0-9]+'` really okay for all circumstances? e.g. for a figure like `c('23,3')` compared to `c('12l.120.222.23,3')` and actually I wanted know wheter there is a function for such a situation in general. Thanks!

Comment: `taRifx::destring` does something like what you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a function that uses `gsub` to deal with the sample data you posted:

```
x <- c('2.200.222   €', '  180.109,3 €', '28,42 m²', '47,70 m²')

strip <- function(x){
  z <- gsub("[^0-9,.]", "", x)
  z <- gsub("\\.", "", z)
  gsub(",", ".", z)
}

as.numeric(strip(x))
[1] 2200222.00  180109.30      28.42      47.70
```

---

It works like this:

1. First strip out all trailing non-digits (and anything after these non-digits)
2. Then strip out all periods.
3. Finally, convert commas to periods.

Comment: Your first regexp only needs to be `"[^0-9,.]+"`

Comment: Also you don't need to escape `.` in the replacement in the 3rd regexp.